# What is the expected volume of the simplex formed by $n+1$ points independently uniformly distributed on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$?

Tags: probability, geometry, volume, spheres, geometric-probability

I was surprised that I couldn’t find this question answered on this site (not for lack of trying). I need the result for answering [Probability of random sphere lying inside the unit ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555686), so I’m posting it as a separate question and answer for future reference.

> What is the expected volume of the simplex formed by $n+1$ points independently uniformly distributed on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$?

MathWorld has the answers $\frac3{2\pi}$ for $n=2$ under [Circle Triangle Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleTrianglePicking.html) and $\frac{4\pi}{105}$ for $n=3$ under [Sphere Tetrahedron Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphereTetrahedronPicking.html), but the general result is surprisingly hard to find.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter could explain the downvote. This is the second time I'm getting a quick downvote for a question that I'm immediately answering myself; perhaps the downvoter is not aware of the fact that this is explicitly encouraged – see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 5):

The question is answered in [Isotropic Random Simplices](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1426176) by R. E. Miles (Advances in Applied Probability, 3(2), 353–382) in Theorem $2$ on p. $362$. More generally, for $i$ points independently uniformly distributed in the interior of the $n$-ball and $j$ points independently uniformly distributed on its boundary (the sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1}$), with $1\le r:=i+j-1\le n$ so that the points almost surely form an $r$-simplex, the moments of the volume $\Delta$ of this simplex are

$$
E\left[\Delta^k\right]
=\\
\frac1{r!^k}\left(\frac n{n+k}\right)^i\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12(r+1)(n+k)-j+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12[(r+1)n+rk]-j+1\right)}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12[n+k]\right)}\right)^r\prod_{l=1}^{r-1}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12[n-r+k+l]\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12[n-r+l]\right)}\;.
$$

In our case, $i=0$, $j={n+1}$, $r=n$ and $k=1$, so the desired volume is

$$
A_n=\frac1{n!}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12n^2+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12n^2\right)}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12n+\frac12\right)}\right)^n\prod_{l=1}^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12l+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12l\right)}\;.
$$

With

\begin{eqnarray}
\Xi(n):=\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(n)}
\end{eqnarray}

this becomes

$$
A_n=\frac1{n!}\Xi\left(\frac{n^2}2\right)\Xi\left(\frac n2\right)^{-n}\prod_{l=1}^{n-1}\Xi\left(\frac l2\right)\;.
$$

Thus, with

\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&\frac12&1&\frac32&2&\frac92&8\\\hline
\Xi(n)&\frac1{\sqrt\pi}&\frac{\sqrt\pi}2&\frac2{\sqrt\pi}&\frac{3\sqrt\pi}4&\frac{128}{35\sqrt\pi}&\frac{6435\sqrt\pi}{4096}\\
\end{array}

we find

$$
A_2=\frac12\frac{\Xi(2)\Xi\left(\frac12\right)}{\Xi(1)\Xi(1)}=\frac3{2\pi}
$$

and

$$
A_3=\frac1{3!}\frac{\Xi\left(\frac92\right)\Xi\left(\frac12\right)\Xi(1)}{\Xi\left(\frac32\right)\Xi\left(\frac32\right)\Xi\left(\frac32\right)}=\frac{4\pi}{105}\;,
$$

in agreement with the MathWorld values, and also

$$
A_4=\frac1{4!}\frac{\Xi(8)\Xi\left(\frac12\right)\Xi(1)\Xi\left(\frac32\right)}{\Xi(2)\Xi(2)\Xi(2)\Xi(2)}=\frac{6435}{31104\pi^2}\;.
$$

Comment: In all the products, there is a variable $l$ that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.  Should the index be $l$ instead of $i$ everywhere?

Comment: @saulspatz: Thanks, yes, I've fixed it.

Comment: note your product telescopes: you can write $\prod_{l=1}^{n-1} \Xi(l/2) = \frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}$ (not sure if this is any nicer since you're using $\Xi$ instead of $\Gamma$)